# If I get banned from a game and my team wins, do I get a win?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

If I get banned for teamkilling in competetive and a few rounds later the remaining 4 people on my team finish the game with a victory, will I get a victory aswell, even though I'm not in the game?

Comment: My instincts say no, since, after all, you didn't really help the win.

Comment: Well you just didn't finish the game. That doesn't mean you didn't help the win. You could get banned at 15-0 after carrying the game.

Comment: Yes, but I'm going to guess that it's the same as leaving for any reason at all. You wouldn't get credit for leaving right away, and you probably don't get credit for team killing late in the game.

Answer (score 8):

If you get kicked/banned from a match it counts as a LOSS regardless of the result of the match. So that means you can even rank down because you got kicked.

Comment: Ranking up and down doesn't have to do with win or lose in particular. It all depends on your points compared to the average of your team and compared to the average on the enemy team. Despite of that, his information about a LOSS is absolutely correct. :)

Comment: @Trollwut It is true that ones stats within the match does affect your Elo-rating. But winning or losing is critical in the amount of Elo-points you will gain/lose. I've tried it myself, I got banned for 30min about 10 rounds into a match and i ranked down from LEM to LE.

Comment: Is this really true if you're kicked by a vote from your teammates? I'd be very surprised if so.

Comment: @Decency Yes it's true. Although I've read something about valve making it so that if it is a 4-man premade team that kicks you, it won't count as a loss. But i can't confirm that.

Comment: do you have any source? or are you just speculating? or what?

Answer (score 2):

A kick or an abandon is almost always detrimental to your Elo/rank. It is either as severe as a loss or worse. However, there is one scenario in which a kick will result in no detriment: if 4 individuals are lobbied up together and they decide to kick you, you will not receive any penalty as either a ban or a negative effect on your rank.

Comment: do you have any source? or are you just speculating? or what?