# If I quit a competitive match early, do I still get the victory and xp?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I was playing my competitive match just a few minutes ago. I was leading both teams by many kills. But then my brother slammed my laptop shut while I was in game and ran away with it.

I assume my laptop went to sleep, which would probably count as quitting the match. Would I get the victory and the xp for the match?

Comment: "Slammed" your computer? What do you mean by this?

Comment: @DJPirtu I'm interpreting that as slamming a laptop shut, although I could easily be wrong.

Comment: It's a laptop , sorry my bad . He slammed it shut.

Comment: What does he have currently?

Comment: It all depends... Did you hear a robotic Valve voice coming out from the game, right at the moment the laptop was slammed, saying: "Oh dear God!"

Comment: Who has what currently? @ohnno

Comment: Don't think I did :P @uygar.raf

Comment: @thatguyonthenet he's asking what the "it" your brother currently has is referring to.

Comment: @Ohnooo I think he robbed it :-D = `He has it currently`. Nevertheless: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/240981/125433 that is the answer

Comment: The laptop , if you were referring to that

Comment: Why don't you just get your computer back and check what happened?

Comment: Don't know where the hell he is he might've gone to his friends for all I know. Is there another way to check it because this match was kind of the first match which I won MVP 6 times in a row and 2 aces

Comment: I don't have my laptop :P @hoch

Comment: CS:GO is hardly browser-based and so you can't check much outside of the game launcher. But I assume you won't lose your laptop forever and get it back soon, but I can say that even when you win 16-0 with 80-0-0 score this wouldn't boost you that hard. You have to play constantly well what will raise your amount of wins and your skill group.

Comment: I get that but is there a chance of me not getting anything at all (assuming I'm not kicked from the match itself)

Comment: And yes , I know one good match can't make a huge difference but you have to agree when going up higher it gets harder and you should take what you can get

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If I get banned from a game and my team wins, do I get a win?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/167446/if-i-get-banned-from-a-game-and-my-team-wins-do-i-get-a-win)

Answer (score 2):

Since what almost certainly happened as a result of this is a disconnect, the match will be marked as a loss, and you will receive a competitive cooldown for abandoning the match, despite it not being your fault per se. If you haven't received a competitive cooldown recently, the cooldown will last 30 minutes.

On the off chance that you ended up staying connected but idle, that's also a competitive cooldown. You do not recieve credit for anything if you are kicked from a match by the competitive cooldown system.

> **Possible reasons for a cooldown:**
>
> **Abandoning a match**
>
> Leaving a competitive match mid-game, through direct player action or in-action. Losing network connection while in-game will yield the same result as abandoning a match. - ([Source](http://counterstrike.wikia.com/wiki/Competitive#Competitive_matchmaking_cooldown))

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get points and not be present till the very end of the game is if you get kicked AFTER the final kill of the game. I do believe they introduced this at the same time they fixed "surrender during half time to win" bug. In any other case - as far as the server is concerned you were kicked/banned for a reason and therefore don't get any MM points.

Slightly different case is hacking. If there were a hacker on your team, you win, and he gets VACed later on, you will lose the MM points for that game (ONLY). And in the same way, if you lost against a hacker, that got banned later, you will get points even though you lost.

Answer (score -1):

No you dont, also you get a competitive cooldown. You can check the offical wikia for these type of questions, im sure youll have your answer faster.

Comment: Is there a source to back up your answer?

Comment: It should be on the offical wikia i guess?

Comment: Then you can add that in your answer. As it stands, your answer is a little bit sparse.

Comment: ...uh. You may want to add a direct link to this source. We tend to frown upon answer that require further Googling.